# How do I resolve not fully installed package (python3-setuptools)?

Tags: apt, python, dpkg

I was trying to install python3-setuptools, and when i run

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3-setuptools (0.6.34-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython import files as dpf
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 25, in <module>
    from debpython.pydist import PUBLIC_DIR_RE
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/pydist.py", line 28, in <module>
    from debpython.tools import memoize
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/tools.py", line 25, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
ImportError: /usr/bin/datetime.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
dpkg: error processing python3-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-setuptools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoclean`, `apt-get remove python3-setuptools`, `dpkg --remove python3-setuptools`, `apt-get install -f`, `dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq`, `dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq` and `dpkg --purge`, but none of them worked.

---

Output of `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq python3-setuptools`

```
(Reading database ... 225309 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3-setuptools ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 32, in <module>
    from debpython import files as dpf
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 25, in <module>
    from debpython.pydist import PUBLIC_DIR_RE
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/pydist.py", line 28, in <module>
    from debpython.tools import memoize
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/tools.py", line 25, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
ImportError: /usr/bin/datetime.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
dpkg: error processing python3-setuptools (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 36, in <module>
    from debpython import files as dpf
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 25, in <module>
    from debpython.pydist import PUBLIC_DIR_RE
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/pydist.py", line 28, in <module>
    from debpython.tools import memoize
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/tools.py", line 25, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
ImportError: /usr/bin/datetime.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install -f` to resolve it.
This will attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies.

Comment: I get same error when i do that

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get remove python3-setuptools --purge`

Comment: Same error again :/